# jQuery - attr('class') getting parent class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get class of an element, but it shows its parent class if current element class is empty.

I just want to check if current element has class if not do nothing but dont show parent class

```
$('*').click(function(){
    var class_of_el = $(this).attr('class').replace('test', '').replace('test2', '');
    alert(class_of_el);
});
```

here is the fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/howtoplease/cpENU/

Comment: `*` not an element...but the entire doc

Comment: Can I use `e.stopPropagation();` here

Comment: You have to use `target`

Comment: More details here http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Comment: @ubercooluk There's no need to use `target`. jQuery always sets `$(this)` to the target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the event is propagating.

Try this:

```
$('*').click(function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
    var class_of_el = $(this).attr('class').replace('test', '').replace('test2', '');
    alert(class_of_el);
});
```

Now when clicking an element without a class, nothing happens, but if you click an element with a class it will be `alert`ed.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpENU/1/)

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery('*')](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/) selects all elements, That's why you are getting parent element class name also.

When you add null check with class, you can see, it returns value for each element. i.e.

```
$('*').click(function(){
    var class_of_el = $(this).attr('class') != undefined? $(this).attr('class').replace('test', '').replace('test2', '') : 'empty';
    alert(class_of_el);
});
```

Here is the [demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/cpENU/3/)

Answer (score 1):

It could be a bad idea to register `click` event handlers to all elements in the document and to prevent event propagation from them.

```
$(document).on('click', '*', function(e){
    if(e.target == this){
        console.log($(this).attr('class'))
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5f9ax/)

Answer (score 1):

As said by winterblood, the event is progating to the parent element because you selected every element on the page.
However, I would also like to add that if your objective is to check for a specific class, you can use `hasClass` instead of parsing the `class` attribute.

```
$('*').click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    var isTest = $(this).hasClass('test');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you should stop event to bubble to outer elements-

you can do something like this

```
$('*').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();  // This will stop bubbling of event
    var class_of_el = $(this).attr('class').replace('test', '').replace('test2', '');
    alert(class_of_el);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cpENU/6/

Comment: How is this any different to my answer above?

Comment: i didn't check your answer